# Rudin's Functional Analysis Chapter 6 problem 20

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Prove that every continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is of the form $f$ maps to $\lambda f$ where $\lambda$ is a distribution with compact support on in $\Omega$.

Well my idea is that if we have a continuous functional on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then also on $D_K$ for every compact set $K$ in $\Omega$, hence by proven result on distributions we know that since it is continuous on every $D_K$ then it is also continuous on $D(\Omega)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Denote by $p_{K,n}$ the seminorm
$$f \mapsto p_{K,n}(f) = \sup_{x\in K, 0\le l \le n} |f^{(l)}(x)|$$

The topology of $C^{\infty}$ is given by the seminorms $p_{K,n}$, for $K$ compact in $\Omega$, $n \ge 0$. Since the map $\lambda$ is continuous there exists $K$, $n$, and $C>0$ so that
$$|\lambda f| \le C\cdot p_{K,n}(f)$$

Let now $K_1$ any other compact inside $\Omega$. For $f \in D_{K_1}$ we have
$$p_{K,n}(f) = p_{K_1 \cap K, n}(f) \le p_{K_1, n}(f)$$ so we get
$$|\lambda f| \le C \cdot p_{K_1, n}$$
Hence, $\lambda$ is continuous on $D_{K_1}$.  Therefore, $\lambda \in D'_{\Omega}$. Notice also that $\operatorname{supp} \lambda \subset K$.

The converse is a bit more delicate: Say we have a distribution with compact support $K \subset \Omega$.

Consider a conpact $K_1\subset \Omega$ so that $K \subset \overset{\circ}K_1$. We have an open cover  $\Omega= \overset{\circ}K_1\cup (\Omega\backslash K)$. Let now $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ a partition of unity corresponding to this cover, that is $\psi_i$ are smooth, $\operatorname{supp}\psi_1 \subset  \overset{\circ}K_1$, $\operatorname{supp}\psi_1 \subset \Omega\backslash K$.

Let now $\phi \in D_{\Omega}$. We have 
$$\phi = \psi_1 \cdot \phi + \psi_2 \cdot \phi$$

Note that the support of $\psi_2 \cdot \phi$ is compact and contained in 
$\Omega\backslash K$. Therefore, $\lambda(\psi_2 \cdot \phi) = 0$. 
Now, $\psi_1 \cdot \phi \in D_{K_1}$. Therefore
$$|\lambda ( \psi_1 \phi)| \le C \cdot p_{K_1, n}(\psi_1 \cdot \phi)$$

However, from Leibniz differentiation formula we get 
$$p_{K_1, n}(\psi_1 \cdot \phi)\le C_1 \cdot p_{K_1, n}(\phi)$$ for all $\phi$

Comment: I don't understand how it follows that the support of $\lambda$ also lies in the the set K, and how is the choice of K not arbitrary?

Comment: Please provide a complete solution with proper explanation

Comment: @orangeskid: Why do you say that there **exists** some K, n and C? Shouldn't it be the case that for every K, there are N and C such that the conclusion holds?